# It's showing error - Variable does not exist: CreatedById

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger AssignToReportingManager on User (After update) {
    String query,userId,reportingManId;
    List<sObject> sObjectList = new List<sObject>();
    //Set<Id> userId = new Set<Id>();
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    List<SObject>getSobjectList = new List<SObject>();
    List<SObject>addSobjectList = new List<SObject>();
    List<List<SObject>> sObjectsList = new List<List<SObject>>();

    //Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(User u : Trigger.New){
        if(u.isActive==false){   
            //userId.add(u.id);
            userId = u.id;
            reportingManId = u.Reporting_Manager__c;
        }
    }

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    for(String str: schemaMap.keySet()){
        System.debug('---'+schemaMap.get(str));
        String str1 = String.valueOf(schemaMap.get(str));
        if(str1 == 'Account' || str1 =='Contact' || str1 =='Opportunity' || str1 =='Lead' || str1 =='Order'){
            getSobjectList = Database.query('SELECT ID , CreatedById FROM   '+schemaMap.get(str)+'  WHERE createdById =\'' + userId + '\''); 
            //List<sObject>getSobjectList = Database.query(query);     
            sObjectsList.add(getSobjectList);   
            System.debug('------'+ getSobjectList);
            System.debug('++++++'+ sObjectsList);  
        }           
    }
    for(List<SObject>sObjList : sObjectsList){
        if(sObjList.getSObjectType()==schemaMap.get('Account')||sObjList.getSObjectType()==schemaMap.get('Contact')||
           sObjList.getSObjectType()==schemaMap.get('Lead')||sObjList.getSObjectType()==schemaMap.get('Opportunity')){
           for(SObject sObj : sObjList){
               System.debug('---------'+sObj);
               sObj.CreatedById = reportingManId; 
               addSobjectList.add(sObj);
           }     
        }

    }
    //if(!addSobjectList.isEmpty()){
    //    update addSobjectList;
   // }        
}
```

I Don't know , why it's getting error because Account,Contact,Lead and Opportunity CreatedById Api Name is available, Please hepl me for solve out this problem , show me where i'm doing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop:

```
      for(SObject sObj : sObjList){
          System.debug('---------'+sObj);
          sObj.CreatedById = reportingManId; 
          addSobjectList.add(sObj);
      }
```

you are telling the compiler that the type of `sObj` is the base class `SObject` which only has an `Id` property defined, rather than a specific concrete SObject type, such as `Contact`, that has (many) additional properties such as `CreatedById` defined. While this does allow your code to work for multiple concrete SObject types, it means you have to slightly change your approach to accessing properties.

So one way to fix this is to change to use the [map-like methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) of the base `SObject` class:

```
          sObj.put('CreatedById', reportingManId);
```

Here you are essentially saying "hey compiler, I know that all the concrete types I am using here have a `CreatedById` property, so don't get in my way".

**PS**

Note that only writable fields can be set, and as you have discovered, `CreatedById` is not writeable.

Comment: Thanks but when i'm trying using this then it's getting error at time for trigger execution and the error is 'System.SObjectException: Field CreatedById is not editable: Trigger.AssignToReportingManager: line 38, column 1.'

Comment: It's showing CreatedById isn't editable , is there any solution for this non editable filed accessability.

Comment: @ManishMourya My bad. AFAIK in this sort of Apex code, you can't "cheat". The platform sets that field.